# inheriting a vector/array/list and changing its size

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector

Newbie here on inheritance. 
Im trying to define a vector in a parent class for instance :

```
    class Parent
    {
      public:
         vector<Parent*>functions;   
    };

    class child : public Parent
    {
       public: 
         int change_size()
         { 
           functions.pushback(x)         
           return functions.size(); // here it changes to 1;
         }
    };
    class child2 : public Parent
    {
       public:

       int size() { return functions.size();}// here it is still 0;
    };
```

when inheriting that vector from the Parent class, I can only change the size temporarily (in that specific sub-class). Is there a possible way where one can globablly (throughout all other sub-classes) change it and save it to the newest updated?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking. Please try to create a [mcve] and post it.

Comment: `pubic` - that is why you should not try to type your code in the browser, but prepare an actual example offline

Comment: If you want all objects to share the same vector you have to make it static.  As is each instance will have it' own.

Comment: The meaning of "change size temporarily" is not clear.  Nor "all other sub-clases".  Nor "save it".  Nor "newest updated".

Comment: Different class instances do not share non-`static` member variables. Inheritance does not change this fact

Comment: You can't change the size of an array.

Comment: I suspect this already works the way you want it to. Can you provide a few extra lines of code to make a full working example and explain what it does that you don't want it to do?

Comment: "I can only change the size temporarily (in that specific sub-class)." Unfortunately you are mis-reading these results. You can change the size for *one specific object*, not for the class as a whole. If you make 10 `child`s each `child` will have its own `functions`.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a `static` variable:

```
class Parent
{
  public:
     static vector<Parent*> functions;   
};
```

But then this is "global" for all classes and other objects.

Remember that `static` variables have to be instantiated outside your class, that means in a cpp file.

```
vector< Parent* > Parent::functions;
```

Comment: Getting error LNK2001 when I'm trying this.

Comment: You need to declare it in the class and in one of the .cpp files, such as `vector<Parent *> Parent::functions;`.

Comment: Updated the answer.